# ApplicationInsights - Create Rules via REST

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-rest-api

I am trying to find a way how to create ApplicationInsight rules via REST. I will be calling these from a C# application.

I have found the following documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/operations/list which if called exposes all the functions available. The problem is that these functions are not documented thus calling them will be super challenging.

Has anyone ever attempted this before?

Comment: What do you mean `ApplicationInsight rules`?

Comment: Hi Jim, I meant Azure Monitor rules.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking under the wrong section in the docs.

This is what I was after https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricalerts